# Storing user inputs without declaring an arbitrarily large array.

Tags: c

I am taking character input and storing it without declaring an arbitrarily large array. Problem is that the code does not print the values stored (although it perfectly prints the number of elements that I enter). The working principle is: in the first for loop execution "b" is created and "c" is copied to it(c right now contains something arbitrary),then user overwrites whatever is there in "b" then the updated "b" is copied to "c". In the second and following loop executions "c" is basically the old "b" and "b" is constantly updated by copying "c" to it and entering new element at the end.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char e = 'a';   
    char *b,*c = &e;    
    printf("start entering the characters and enter Z to terminate:\n");
    char d;
    int i,m;    
    for(i=0;(d=getchar()) != 'Z';i++)
    {
        b=malloc(sizeof(char)*(i+1));
    strcpy(b,c);        
    scanf("%c",b+i);
    c=malloc(sizeof(char)*(i+1));
    strcpy(c,b);
    }
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    int q=strlen(b);    
    printf("%d\n",q);
    //printf("%s\n",b);
    for(m=0;m<q;m++)
        printf("%c",b[m]);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: (1)The C string that ends with '\0' is not considered. (2)Input is consumed in two places. (3)using `realloc` is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the question code uses both 'getchar()' as well as 'scanf()'; perhaps I am missing something?

And, as mentioned by 'BLUEPIXY', realloc() is better.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main()
        {
        char   *b    = NULL;  /* This will be the reference to the self-growing array. */
        size_t  bLen = 0;     /* This is the length of the string in 'b' (not counting the string termination character.) */

        for(;;)
          {
          char *x; /* Used to safely grow the array 'b' larger. */
          int d;   /* Use an 'int'.  'getchar()' returns an 'int', (not a 'char'). */

          /* Get a character from stdin. */
          d=getchar();
          if('Z' == d)
             break;

           /* Safely grow the array 'b' large enough to hold the one more character. */
          x=realloc(b, (bLen+1) * sizeof(*b));
          if(NULL == x)
             {
             fprintf(stderr, "realloc() failed.\n");
             exit(1);
             }
          b=x;

          /* Store the character in the array and re-terminate the string. */
          b[bLen++] = d;
          b[bLen] = '\0';
          }

        printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("%s\n",b);

       if(b)
          free(b);

        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: i know its too late, perhaps i was too lethargic !! but i really learnt a lot from the replys and your code and deployed both the ways i.e "Reallocating memory during every iteration of the loop" and "allocating a small amount of space at the outset and then increasing it". –  user3647970 just now

Comment: i wanted to ask one thing...is it really necessary or why are you creating char *x and then equating b=x. instead what is wrong if we do: b=realloc(b, (bLen+1) * sizeof(*b)); i think this should also work.

Comment: @user3647970, perhaps for this small example, you could ` b=realloc(b, (bLen+1) * sizeof(*b));`, as you suggest.  However there is a risk, such that this should -never- be done in production code. The risk a memory leak if 'realloc()' fails.  Specifically, when 'realloc()' fails it returns 'NULL'; hence, in the risky version, 'b' will be set to NULL.  This would be unfortunate because (beforehand), it contained the address of a previously allocated chunk of memory.  After 'realloc()' returns 'NULL', this chunk of memory remains allocated; but 'b' now contains 'NULL'... (continued)...

Comment: ...(continued)... and your program has no reference to the previously allocated memory; and hence has no way to free it.  This is what is termed a 'memory leak'; which causes havoc in -many- production applications.  Hence, it is best to receive the newly allocated memory address from 'realloc()' using another pointer.  Then after testing to see that it is not 'NULL', it is safe to assign that value to 'b'.  In reality, this is a design problem with 'realloc()' that all professional programmers have to work with.  It would have been better if 'realloc()' were designed better than it is.

Answer (score 0):

Some impressions:

1. Giving all of your variables single-character names makes it a lot harder than it should be for someone reading this code to figure out what you're trying to do.
2. When you're done with a block of memory that you have allocated using `malloc()`, you need to release it using `free()`.
3. `strcpy()` is for use with null-terminated strings, so I don't think it's going to do what you expect here. Consider `memcpy()` instead. Your use of `strlen()` has the same problem. You shouldn't need to replace that with anything, since `i` should already give you the character count.
4. Is your `scanf()` statement trying to copy a character into your buffer? Just use a simple assignment, `like b[i] = d`.
5. If `Z` is the user's first keypress, `b` will never be initialized, and Bad Things will happen when you try to access it in the code following the loop.
6. Reallocating memory during every iteration of the loop is very inefficient. Instead, consider allocating a small amount of space at the outset—say, 20 characters' worth. Then in the body of your loop, if your buffer has enough space to accommodate a new character, all you need to do is copy that one character. If your buffer lacks space, then reallocate a larger block of memory, but not just for 1 extra character; reserve space for another 20 (or whatever).
7. Each reallocation should only require one call to `malloc()` (or, even better, `realloc()` as suggested by BLUEPIXY). I'm not sure why you're using two.
8. Null-terminate the input at the end so you can treat it like a string when you want to display it.

I'm happy to help if you have specific questions about any of this.

Comment: i know its too late, perhaps i was too lethargic !! but i really learnt a lot from the replys and the code provided by @mahonrimoriancumer and deployed both the ways i.e "Reallocating memory during every iteration of the loop" and "allocating a small amount of space at the outset and then increasing it".

Comment: i wanted to ask one thing...in the code provided by @mahonri is it really necessary or why are you creating char *x and then equating b=x. instead what is wrong if we do: b=realloc(b, (bLen+1) * sizeof(*b)); i think this should also work.

Comment: @user3647970,  It is actually very important in professional C programming.  If realloc() fails, it returns 'NULL'; but does not free the original memory pointed to by 'b'.  Hence, capturing the return value of realloc() in 'b', and if realloc() fails, your program no longer has a reference to the original memory pointed to by 'b'; and hence, there is no way to properly free() that original memory (ie: 'memory leak').  For a academic program as that in the question there is no real problem; however it would be very bad in a program that consistently leaks memory for a long period of time.